# LumenWorks Csv Reader - How do I detect columns that are present in the data rows but not in the columns?

Tags: c#, csv

I'm using the LumenWorks CsvReader to parse a file with the following structure.

```
heading1,heading2,heading3
data1,data2,data3,data4,data5
```

The code detects that I've got three fields per row because I've got three headings. It happily allows me to parse the first row and retrieve data1, data2, and data3, but i can't access data4 or data5. At the very least, I'd like to be able to detect additional fields in the data rows. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks!

Comment: what code are you using to hide the other two fields?

Comment: I'm not using any code to hide the fields. I'm trying to find a way to read them and I can't.

Answer (score 2):

It does this because it uses the first row to know how many columns your file has. If you change the first row to "heading1,heading2,heading3,," it will work as expected.

Comment: Not sure if this is correct, but certainly would be the first thing I'd try... +1 to cancel the -1.  The other thing I wondered is if you could manually add headers 4 and 5, after the initial parse. Sadly, it appears the `_fieldHeaders` array is private and can't be modified (not that I'm sure it would have worked, but worth a shot!)

Answer (score 0):

I expect that you won't be able to read the data in those fields. Rather, I expect that an error is being raised and you're not seeing it. This would at least allow you to detect that those other fields exist in the data.

Try setting the DefaultParseErrorAction enum property so that you ensure you're seeing any errors being raised. I would have expected the scenario you describe to trigger a MalformedCsvException (if you have set the DefaultParseErrorAction = ParseErrorAction.ThrowException). You could also set DefaultParseErrorAction = ParseErrorAction.RaiseEvent and then attach an event handler to the ParseError event. Finally, you should be able to just check if the ParseErrorFlag is true after each record.

HTH

Comment: huh. I've tried setting the DefaultParseErrorAction to throw exception and it doesn't throw anything. I also tried checking the ParseErrorFlag; still, no luck. Thanks for your suggestion :S